# WPF Button isPressed and isEnabled problem

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, expression-blend

Update: using Expression Blend 3

I'm trying to style the IsPressed & IsEnabled(false) property triggers for a class of buttons in a WPF application.

Here's a UserControl with a Button using the style...

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="Kiosk.ButtonTest"
    x:Name="UserControl">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{DynamicResource BlueButton}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Content="Button" Height="52.9"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And here's the style fragment...

```
   <!-- Blue Button -->
   <Style x:Key="BlueButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BlueGradient3}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource DarkGradient1}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BlueGradient3}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource DarkGradient1}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BlueGradient1}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BlueGradient1}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BlueGradient2}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="TextBox.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>       
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Trebuchet MS"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
    <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{DynamicResource KioskStandardDropShadow}" />
</Style>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="BlueGradient1" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF3FA2FD" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF014782" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="BlueGradient2" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF014782" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF3FA2FD" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="BlueGradient3" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF014782" Offset="1"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF0B2135" Offset="0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DarkGradient1" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF2A2A2A" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF474747" Offset="0.478"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF323232" Offset="0.487"/>
    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF282828" Offset="0.681"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
    <!-- Regular Drop Shadow --> 
    <DropShadowEffect x:Key="KioskStandardDropShadow" Opacity="0.6" BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="5" Direction="308"/>
<!-- fragment end -->
```

The Default and Mouse over changes work fine, but isEnabled false and isPressed true still show the Button default colors.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i tried your code and it works for me : default-light blue, mouseover-dark blue, IsPressed-Gray, Disabled - Gray. i do however removed setter for FocusVisualStyle because you didn't include it.

Comment: This is not an answer, I know, but try the Visual State Manager.

Comment: You can edit your question to add the extra code rather than posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fixed it after studying the code at http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2007/07/creating-custom-wpf-button-template-in.html...

This is what I ended up with, which works great.

```
<!-- Blue Button -->
<Style x:Key="BlueButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Name="border" 
                    BorderThickness="2"
                    Padding="4,2" 
                    BorderBrush="{DynamicResource BlueGradient2}"
                    CornerRadius="5" 
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid >
                    <ContentPresenter 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                Name="content"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BlueGradient3}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource DarkGradient1}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BlueGradient3}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource DarkGradient1}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BlueGradient1}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BlueGradient1}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BlueGradient2}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="TextBox.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>       
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Trebuchet MS"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15pt"/>
    <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{DynamicResource KioskStandardDropShadow}" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the ControlTemplate to change the background color of your button.

Here is one I copied from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.aspx) that works well with your code.
You can merge your specific overrides to this style.

**EDIT:**
To make the following style work, as is, you need to download the [Styling with Control Templates Sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=160041) from Microsoft.  If you include Button.xaml and Shared.xaml from the sample the following style should work because these two files contain all the StaticResoruces listed the XAML below.  I am testing in Visual Studio 2008.

Here is how I chanaged the user conttrol:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ButtonPressed.Views.KioskButton"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  Height="300" Width="300">

  <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary 
              Source="Button.xaml">
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Content="Button" Height="52.9"/>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here is part of the button style from Button.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
  <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
  <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="23"/>
  <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="75"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Border 
          x:Name="Border"  
          CornerRadius="2" 
          BorderThickness="1"
          Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"
          BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}">
          <ContentPresenter 
            Margin="2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DefaultedBorderBrush}" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DefaultedBorderBrush}" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DarkBrush}" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PressedBorderBrush}" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Adding this as a Style (with x:Key="CustomButton" to reference it) to Expression Blend, just gives an "Invalid XAML" error.

Comment: I added the references to where to find the StaticResources.

Comment: Unfortunately Styling with ControlTemplates Sample won't work with Expression Blend 3.

But it's ok, I added an answer that works with it.

Comment: Works fine for me in Blend 3. I do need to open Button.xaml as a resource but the message from Blend makes that obvious.