# How to keep the background of a button the same while it is pressed?

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, background, click

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF Button isPressed and isEnabled problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518146/wpf-button-ispressed-and-isenabled-problem)

Here is a snippet of code from an application that I am developing using WPF and XAML. What I am trying to do is get the button's background to stay the same color when it is clicked on by the user as it is when it is not clicked on by the user.

Note: There is an image in the button.

```
<Button Name="Button1" Background="#3852A4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Width="35" Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="swapGd1andGd2">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="#3852A4" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
    <Image Source="Images/112_DownArrowShort_Grey_24x24_72.png" Width="24" Height="24" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
</Button>`
```

My question is, why doesn't this code produce the results that I want?

Comment: And if you can tell me how to format this code better please tell me. Fairly new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Agreed.  Possibly merge my answer over?  The other one doesn't mention why just setting the style doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In wpf buttons have a default template that overrides style values.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518146/wpf-button-ispressed-and-isenabled-problem) for an example of how to change the value using a template.

Comment: Thanks man. I've worked on this on and off for a few days and it's just not working like I want it to. I'm just going to abandon this feature, it's taking to much time.