# WPF Style Trigger Sets Button Foreground on IsPressed, but not Background

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following XAML code, which creates a window with a single button. When I click the button, the foreground color changes to red, but the background color does not change. Why does the one change, but not the other?

```XAML
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfExperiments"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,2">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" 
                Content="Button"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="135,97,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Width="75"
                />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I've Googled this first, of course. Most of what I've found says the fix is to use a template instead of a style, which I'm certainly willing to do if that's the solution. But I noticed in [one SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977254/how-to-keep-the-background-of-a-button-the-same-while-it-is-pressed) that buttons have default templates that override style values. If so, why does my XAML affect the foreground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the foreground isn't affected because the button's default template doesn't update the foreground when the button is pressed. it update only the background.
the default template's triggers are executed after the style's triggers, this is why your background isn't affected by your style.
more explanation are in here 
http://harishasanblog.blogspot.com/2011/02/ismouseover-trigger-not-working-in-wpf.html

Comment: Thanks, that link was very helpful. What I'm after is a simple way to make a WPF button change appearance when the mouse is over it and pressed. I'm kind of amazed that it barely changes, when most of the Windows buttons I've ever seen appear to actually move when you press on them with the mouse pointer. Any suggestions on how to make that happen easily in WPF? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There's a chance that in the Button's Template(ControlTemplate), some trigger changes Background to a different color. By degrees of "strength" its a stronger Trigger than the Style's Trigger, that's why its taking effect. Try editing the Button's Template in style "ButtonStyle" you posted and putting your trigger there.

Comment: Will do. Any links to documentation on this? I suppose I could just dump the button's template and read it directly, but it's good to have the book.